# A column has many multiple mispelled or similar values. How to set the correct values using some rules?

Tags: pandas

I have combined multiple dataframes, and the resulting dataframe df, has three columns 'Date', 'Product', 'Price'.

There are many rows where:

> the 'Product' value is either 'Kiwi' or 'Kiwi '.
> the 'Product' value is either 'apricot' or 'Apricot'.
> the 'Product' value is either 'Apple / imported' or 'Apple / local'

and so on.

I am trying to apply some rules to rename the values such as:

> if value contains 'Kiwi' then set the value as 'Kiwi'
> if value contains 'apricot' then set the value as 'Apricot'
> if value contains 'Apple' then set the value as 'Apple'

Using `df.loc[:,'Product'].sort_values().unique()` and examining the results, I have created a dictionary 'rename_product' containing key:value pairs, where the keys are the texts to search for, and the values are the new values that should be assigned, such as:

```
rename_product = { 
'Kiwi' : 'Kiwi',
'apricot' : 'Apricot',
'Apple' : 'Apple'
}
```

How to proceed to the substitution of values?

Comment: Have you looked at [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) ?

Comment: I have tried `df[df['Product'].str.contains('Kiwi')].replace('Kiwi', inplace = True)` but it doesn't produce any result.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

[pandas replace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/replace-values-in-pandas-dataframe-using-regex/)

your implementation in the comment doesn't seem correct to me. Try implementing one of the solutions in the article I included and see if it works. You can also look at the `re` package. If I remember right though you'll need to use apply and lambda with it to loop through each row in your column.